# How to run openwrt for ppc on qemu?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, openwrt, powerpc

I need to test some compiled files for MPC8377EWLANA

And i don't have hardware yet

Any one knows how to run openwrt on qemu-ppc or may be on some other virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

For arm you can Run like this

`qemu-system-arm -M realview-eb-mpcore -kernel openwrt-realview-vmlinux.elf -net nic -net user -nographic`

similarway you can try

`qemu-system-ppc -M (machine) -kernel (kernel image) -net nic -net user -nographic`

Comment: Give try i m not sure about ppc