# Which files in buildroot are required to run OpenWRT with QEMU?

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, qemu, openwrt

In Fedora20, I have OpenWRT buildroot, I also installed **qemu-system-ppc.x86_64** successfully. Which files are required in order to run OpenWRT with this emulator? Where can I find that files in buildroot? In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893236/2706918) they used only kernel image, but what about filesystem image?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filesystem image. In `menuconfig->Target Images`, select `tar.gz`/ext4 depending on how you want to use qemu. Then generate files will be present inside `bin/{ARCH}/*.tar.gz` or `bin/{ARCH}/*.ext4`

Comment: Thanks @tavish for reply, but what if there will be more than one _bin_ dirs? such as _build_dir/toolchain.../bin_ & _staging_dir/toolchain.../bin_? Which file should be used to specify kernel?

Comment: You do not need those directories. Those are for intermediate compilation steps. The final packages and images will be present in `openwrt_root/bin/{ARCH}/` only. For example `bin/ar71xx/`

Here's an example http://paste.ubuntu.com/12204185/